# How to decode uuencoded PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE struct?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I am trying to programmatically change (using AHK) the wallpaper folder location (album) displayed in the `Personalization > Background` setting in Windows 10. I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1007379/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-slideshow-album-programmatically/1244726) that the `slideshow.ini` file located at `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` contains the information for the location but it is "uuencoded in PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE struct". I tried online uudecoding tools but they fail to decode. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you post the encoded data? I tried to check my own `slideshow.ini` but it's empty

Comment: [Slideshow]
ImagesRootPIDL=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

Comment: @golimar , these are the entire content of the file.

Comment: That's not uuencoded but base64 encoded, and if you base64 decode that you get binary data. You probably need to copy that binary data into a PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE variable in your program

Comment: @golimar in what format should I be decoding it into? UTF-8? Can you refer me to an online tool to do such a conversion? I tried www.base64decode.org but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Edit: I am so stupid. You've clearly written 'binary'. Anyway, I now have the binary data. How do I read it as text? For changing the folder location, I need to be able to edit it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done with AHK. With C language I would to that with `fread` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread?view=msvc-170). That would copy the binary data as-is to a memory buffer, where the Windows code would read and interpret it

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.