In Windows 11, is there any way to change the display background color via the command line?
In Windows 11, is there any way to change the display background color via the command line?
I couldn't find any "official" way to do this.
If there is perhaps some 3rd-party method for accomplishing this under Windows 11, that will also be fine with me.

There is the color command first color code equals background color second color code equals the font color:
ex: green background with black font color:
color 20

Use color /? to see the available colors you can use.

Thank you, but the "color" command only sets the color of the terminal window. I'm looking for a command-line program which would set the color of the display (the screen background) ... or to allow the screen background image to be set via the command line.

Ah, I thought you wanted to change the background color of the command prompt, see if it is this you want: https://superuser.com/questions/850989/change-windows-desktop-background-command-line
